# Boost C++ - Searching Spirit symbol table

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

In Boost Spirit if I have a symbol table

```
struct Foo : boost::spirit::qi::symbols<char, MyEnums::FruitType>
{
    Foo(const std::string& name = std::string("FooTable")
      : boost::spirit::qi::symbols<char, MyEnums::FruitType>(name)
    {
        add("apple", MyEnums::Apple)
           ("orange", MyEnums::Orange)
           ("peach", MyEnums::Peach);
    }
}
```

Later on in my code, if I have the data type how can I get the symbol? For example:

```
Foo fruitSymbolTable;
MyEnums::FruitType fruit = MyEnums::Apple;

std::string fruitTypeString = ???? // want it to be equal to "apple"
```

How can I use the table to get "apple"?

Also, I understand that I can have a table like:

```
struct Foo : boost::spirit::qi::symbols<char, MyEnums::FruitType>
{
    Foo(const std::string& name = std::string("FooTable")
      : boost::spirit::qi::symbols<char, MyEnums::FruitType>(name)
    {
        add("apple", MyEnums::Apple)
           ("apple2", MyEnums::Apple)
           ("orange", MyEnums::Orange)
           ("peach", MyEnums::Peach);
    }
}
```

Where MyEnums::Apple can be either "apple" or "apple2" in which case I'd prefer to get the 'first' match. How can I do this?

Comment: I think you should have called add(MyEnums::Apple, "apple"), etc

Comment: Except that I want "apple" to be parsed to the value of `MyEnums::Apple`. I basically need to go full circle in my parsing.

Comment: You've given me my lunchtime hack. And a good reason to finally bother with `qi::symbols` some more. Spirit's ternary Trie implementation looks pretty useful!

Answer (score 3):

Well, it appears you would like to have a transformation from a `qi::symbols` parser to a `karma::symbols` generator.

I'd say such a thing does not exist. And since you have likely looked for it, I think it is safe to assume it doesn't.

I can see how it would be useful, so you might consider contributing it to Spirit Repository.

I've spent some time here writing a simple mapper that converts from `qi::symbols` to `karma::symbols`:

```
template <typename Char, typename T, typename Lookup, typename Filter>
    karma::symbols<T, std::basic_string<Char> > 
    inverse(qi::symbols<Char,T,Lookup,Filter> const& parser)
{
    karma::symbols<T, std::basic_string<Char> > generator;

    parser.for_each([&generator](std::basic_string<Char> const& symbol, T v) 
        { 
            generator.add(v, symbol); 
        });

    return generator;
}
```

**EDIT** In C++03 style:

```
template <typename Char, typename T, typename Lookup, typename Filter>
    karma::symbols<T, std::basic_string<Char> > 
    inverse(qi::symbols<Char,T,Lookup,Filter> const& parser)
{
    struct _adder { 
        karma::symbols<T, std::basic_string<Char> > result;

        void operator()(std::basic_string<Char> const& symbol, T v) { 
            result.add(v, symbol); 
        }
    } adder;

    parser.for_each(adder);
    return adder.result;
}
```

> **Note** This does **not** yet handle potentially repeatedly mapped values in the parse symbol table.

Here is a simple example program that shows that it works: **[http://liveworkspace.org/code/3uzQKi](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3uzQKi%240)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace qi     = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma  = boost::spirit::karma;

template <typename ItType>
struct parser : public qi::grammar<ItType, int()>
{
    parser() : parser::base_type(start)
    {
        _sym.add("aap", 1)("noot", 2)("mies", 3);
        start = _sym;
    }
  // private:
    qi::symbols<char, int> _sym;
    qi::rule<ItType, int()> start;
};

template <typename ItType>
struct generator : public karma::grammar<ItType, int()>
{
    template<typename Sym>
    generator(Sym&& sym) : generator::base_type(start)
    {
        // _sym.add(1, "aap")(2, "noot")(3, "mies");
        _sym = std::move(sym);
        start = _sym;
    }
  private:
    karma::symbols<int, std::string> _sym;
    karma::rule<ItType, int()> start;
};

template <typename Char, typename T, typename Lookup, typename Filter>
    karma::symbols<T, std::basic_string<Char> > 
    inverse(qi::symbols<Char,T,Lookup,Filter> const& parser)
{
    karma::symbols<T, std::basic_string<Char> > generator;

    parser.for_each([&generator](std::basic_string<Char> const& symbol, T v) 
        { 
            generator.add(v, symbol); 
        });

    return generator;
}

void testcase(std::string const& str)
{
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;

    It begin = str.cbegin();
    It end   = str.cend();

    static const parser<It> p;

    int out;
    bool ok = qi::parse(begin, end, p, out);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ok << '\n';
    std::cout << "remains: '" << std::string(begin, end) << "'\n";
    if (ok)
    {
        std::cout << "parsed value: " << out << "\n";
        static const generator<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator> g(inverse(p._sym));
        std::cout << "generator: " << karma::format(g, out) << "\n";
    }

}

int main()
{
    const auto v = std::vector<std::string>{ "aap", "noot", "mies" };
    for (auto it=v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it)
        testcase(*it);
}
```

Output:

```
true
remains: ''
parsed value: 1
generator: aap
true
remains: ''
parsed value: 2
generator: noot
true
remains: ''
parsed value: 3
generator: mies
```

Comment: How can I accomplish this without using lambda expressions? Specifically how you use parser.for_each()?

Comment: @Addy Erm. You'd write a functor as you would anywhere else: http://liveworkspace.org/code/3WNsqN$0 (also edited post)